# Woocommerce | Иерархический вывод категорий

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Имею чистый **WordPress 5.2.2**

Плагины:

- **elementor pro**
- **woocommerce**

Создал страницу и указал **canvas elementor** (холст), и по-сути сделал небольшой лендинг. В данном контексте тема не влияет практически ни на что, потому-что все основные действия берёт на себя элементор. Задача стоит в том, чтобы вывести иерархически категории на сайте подобно данному скриншоту:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но максимум что удалось сделать, так это данный вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент вывожу все родительские категории, про дочерние не могу никак найти, а если и нахожу, то это относится уже к самой теме, а не к шаблону elementor, поэтому необходимо где-то в коде это править.

В Elementor я нашёл вызов отображения категорий.
**\wp-content\plugins\elementor-pro\modules\woocommerce\widgets\categories.php** функция **get_shortcode()** для возвращения категорий и **render()** для отображения. Точку получения и отрисовки я получил, но остаюсь в полном ступоре как это можно переделать на свой лад. До этого использовав тему я мог плагином переопределить отрисовку категорий. Но с использованием Elementor'а я не могу сообразить где и что править для получения необходимого результата.

Comment: а в чем проблема, если в elementor не нашли нужного блока, создать свой темплейт для вывода категорий и выводить его через шорткод(не обезательно елементором, а можно и в любом месте сайта)?

Comment: или создавайте свой виджет. [Документация](https://developers.elementor.com/creating-a-new-widget/) и [пример](https://github.com/elementor/elementor-hello-world) в помощь.